# Jest: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: jestjs

I added the following in the `package.json` file:

```js
"scripts": {
  "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
},
"jest": {
  "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-node",
  "transform": {}
},
"type": "module",
```

This should be sufficient https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

However, I still have the error:

> export {
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

The source of the error comes from a dependency:
`node_modules\object-array-utils`

The version of Node is v17.4.0

Comment: what is the source of the error, i.e. which file is causing an issue? is it coming from your code or from a 3rd party library?

Comment: @szaman from dependency node_modules\object-array-utils (we updated the question)

Comment: the package was released 3 hours ago, are you the author?

Comment: @szaman yes I am (I'm using these helpers cross-projects, hence we made a lib)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me that there is an issue in the package you're using. It's trying to use ES modules syntax (import / export) but to do that, it needs to declare it in its `package.json` file:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  ...
}
```

See [this guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/es-modules-in-node-today/) for example to get more info about ES modules.

PS. for similar errors / people finding this in the future: locate which package the error is coming from and see if it continues to occur if you remove that package. If not, then the issue is with the package. If you're seeing the same error but for different files, you might have an issue with your jest config.

Comment: why isn't "type" to "module" by default? ehh

Comment: likely for backward compatibility since ES modules are relatively new.

Comment: apparently even when upgrading NodeJS to its latest version. Jeez.

Comment: but hey, thank you so so much for your help!!