# Jest (typescript): SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (lowdb)

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, lowdb

As the title suggests, I am having trouble with jest not allowing an export from the `lowdb` package within my tests. It seems to *only* throw this error for this single package -- the rest of my code is also using ES6 exports and my `package.json` file has the key `type: module`.

**What have I tried**

- Adding type module -- [Jest: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70914025/jest-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export)
- Adding `transformIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!lowdb)"]` -- [Jest setup "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260218/jest-setup-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export)
- Add a transform for `js` which uses `babel-jest` -- [Jest encountered an unexpected token - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70817646/jest-encountered-an-unexpected-token-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export)
- Update my `tsconfig` to output `commonJS` modules
- Update my `tsconfig` to `allowJs:true` and update my jest `transforms` to parse JS with `ts-jest`

I'm not sure where I am going wrong and am sorry in advance if I am being dim.

**This is my TS Config**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "module": "ES6",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "paths": {
      "@services/*": ["services/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["constants/*"],
      "@typeDefs/*": ["typeDefs/*"],
      "@config/*": ["config/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["utils/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["assets/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["rollup.config.ts", "jest.config.ts"]
}
```

And this is my `jest.config.ts` file:

```
import type { Config } from "@jest/types";
import { pathsToModuleNameMapper } from "ts-jest";
import { compilerOptions } from "./tsconfig.json";
// Sync object
const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  verbose: true,
  roots: ["<rootDir>"],
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
  },
  testRegex: ["^.+\\.test\\.ts$"],
  moduleDirectories: ["src", "node_modules"],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths),
};
export default config;
```

Finally, I am invoking jest as follows:

```
"test:ts": "jest --config=jest.config.ts",
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Some additional context

I am pretty sure it should not affect this issue but I figure it could help to provide more context. I am running jest with two different configs -- one for JS and one for TS and the repo to which it relates has some build scripts written in JS that will only ever be run in nodeJS.

The JS config is as follows (has no issues):

```
// Sync object
/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.InitialOptions} */
const config = {
  verbose: true,
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-node",
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],
  transform: {},
  testRegex: ["^.+\\.test\\.js$"],
};

export default config;
```

And it is invoked as follows:

```
"test:js": "yarn node --experimental-vm-modules $(yarn bin jest) --config=jest.config.js",
```

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into similar issue. Here is how I fixed by tweaking jest.config.js:

```
  module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/(?!lowdb|steno)"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js)?$": require.resolve("babel-jest"),
  },
};
```

We want the babel-jest to parse the js files, and the lowDB and one of its dependency -steno.

Next, we need to ensure the babel.config.js to contain the following (we need to configure babel with @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs plugin to correctly parse import/exports and should use importInterop:'node'.

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    test: {
      presets: [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            targets: {
              node: "current",
            },
            modules: "commonjs",
          },
        ],
      ],
      plugins: [
        [
          "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
          {
            importInterop: "node",
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

Ensure you have installed all necessary dev dependencies:

```
 npm i -D babel-jest @babel/core    
 npm i -D @babel/preset-env     
 npm i -D @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs
```